# Mathematica not simplifying trig expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I type in

```
hld01[θ_] = (Cos[θ] Subscript[r, Ty])/(Square[Sin[θ]] Square[
     Sqrt[Square[Csc[θ]] Square[Subscript[r, Ty]]]])
```

and wanted Mathematica to simplify, but it doesn't.  I tried `Simplify[]` and get the same result.  "Clearly" is should be able to simplify `Sqrt[Square[]]`, right? How to get Mathematics to simplify this expression?

Comment: Clearly? Maybe so, if you tell Mathematica that the

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what your expression is supposed to mean. `Square[]` is not a standard Mathematica function and as long as you haven't defined it, it is difficult for Mathematica to know what its square root is supposed to mean.

Assuming you rather meant:

```
hld01[θ_] = (Cos[θ] Subscript[r, Ty])/(Sin[θ]^2 Sqrt[Csc[θ]^2 Subscript[r, Ty]^2]^2)
```

it effortlessly simplifies automatically to

```
Cos[θ]/Subscript[r, Ty]
```

Comment: Thanks!   I was using Square instead of ^2.  The pains of learning something new.:)